# url rewrite then redirect

Tags: url, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

i have a link of file and i want to add something at the end (&download) then redirect to the new modified link

original link 
https://file.example.com/public.php?service=files&t=c2a4f63a15bac9c26815af3c4cd29a59

modified link to redirect
https://file.example.com/public.php?service=files&t=c2a4f63a15bac9c26815af3c4cd29a59&download

the webserver is nginx how is this possible? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `location` block when you manage this link (the first one) you can use directive `set` with variable `$args` as follow:

```
set $args $args&download;
```

Variable `$args` represented query string for current execution. A little longer example:

```
location /public.php {
   set $args $args&download;

   # rest of your code here
}
```

Other way to do this is here:

```
location ~ ^/public.php?service=([^&]+)&t=([^&]+)$ {
   set $args "";   # it's needed for nginx to it doesn't append two times query string
   rewrite .* $uri?$query_string&download;
}

location ~ ^/public.php?(.*)&download$ {
    # do your job here
}
```

Write back is it working for your problem.

Comment: how to get the current public.php parameter as variable?

Comment: it's available in nginx variables `$query_string` or `$args` but this first one is readonly